# Homotopy-theoretic computation of Euler characteristic of skeleton of simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

The Euler Characteristic of the $k$th skeleton of the $n$-simplex is
$$\chi(\mathrm{sk}_k \Delta^n) = \binom{n + 1}{1} - \binom{n + 1}{2} + \cdots + (-1)^{k + 1}\binom{n + 1}{k + 1} = 1 + (-1)^k\binom{n}{k + 1}.$$
Is there a homotopy-theoretic and/or homology-theoretic proof of this fact?

Comment: You basically just gave one: Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant, and a homological algebra computation (as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565228/simplices-and-euler-characteristic?rq=1) shows that you can compute it using either homology or the simplicial chain complex. So compute it using the chain complex, as you did.

Comment: If you want a different argument, you should be able to show that the geometric realization of the $k$-skeleton of an $n$-simplex is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $M$ $k$-spheres, where $M$ is the binomial coefficient in your formula.